# simplier way to add jbutton to jtable

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface, jtable

well i am making this system that has a table, and i have to put buttons in the last column. i've been researching but all the codes i saw are really confusing. there is one tho, but there are still some parts that i didn't understand. here's the site where i got it http://www.javaquery.com/2013/05/how-to-implement-jbutton-in-jtable.html

```
String[] InvoiceArray = new String[20];
//Declare above variable globally. Used by two-three methods. Change variable name as per your need.

/* 
 * import the ButtonColumn class if you are not working in IDE
 * I used formWindowOpened event to load content in Jtable but you can use other event.
 * All you need is put the code with in that event.
 */
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
        Object[][] rowData = new Object[4][2]; // 4: is number of row ; 2: is number of column
        Object columnNames[] = {"Invoice No", "View Report"}; // Name of columns
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            InvoiceArray[i] = i + "-2345";
            rowData[i][0] = i + "-2345";
            rowData[i][1] = "View Order " + i; // Can change the text of button.
        }
        DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
        jTable1.setModel(tm);
        ButtonColumn buttonColumn = new ButtonColumn(jTable1, showOrder, 1); // 1: is column number. column count starts with 0,1,2...
}
```

what's the `InvoiceArray` for? and should i make the `showOrder` from the last line? and also, i didn't understand the code he posted on how to make a listener on it. here it is:

```
Action showOrder = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       //JTable table = (JTable) e.getSource(); // If you have multiple component following the ActionEvent
            int modelRow = Integer.valueOf(e.getActionCommand());
            if (InvoiceArray[modelRow] != null) {
                /* We are placing invoice no in array 
                 * And track the button click index
                 * And fetch index in invoice no
                 */
                System.out.println("Your Invoice No:" + InvoiceArray[modelRow]);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No records found!");
            }
        }
};
```

i know there are some explanations already. i understand some of them but not all. just a simplier way to add jbutton on jtable and also listeners for the jbutton. thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

> just a simplier way to add jbutton on jtable and also listeners for the jbutton.

There is no simple way. You need to understand how renderers and editors work in a JTable. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concepts: Renderers and Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for the basics.

Then you can check out [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) which does the hard work for you. You only need to provide the `Action` to be invoked when you click on the button.

> what's the InvoiceArray for?

It is used to load data into the JTable. This is basic usage of a JTable and has absolutely nothing to do with adding a button to a column of the table.

After the data is loaded you should forget about the invoiceArray. The Action you write should access the data via the TableModel or the JTable.

Comment: can you give me just a very very short codes on how to do it? and i've already checked the Table Button Column, still really confusing and i didn't understand where he added the mnemonic :/

Comment: @luh, You have been given simple code. You create a JTable and add data to it. This is standard JTable processing. The posting assumes you know how to create a JTable with data and add the table to a frame. If you don't know how to do this then read the tutorial for working examples. Then there is 7 lines of code that shows you how to add an Action to delete the row that was clicked. `i didn't understand where he added the mnemonic` - What? Did you see the "setMnemonic(...)" statement? I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: oh i mean why he added the mnemonic? and why he also stated that mnemonic is just optional. what if i take it out will i change anything from his code? and yes i do know how to create jtable with data on it, i just really don't know how to add jbuttons with listeners. and from the sample code, if the `InvoiceArray` is not that important, can i just take it off? and what is the `showOrder` for?

Comment: `i've already checked the Table Button Column,` - so what are your question about that link? Did you download the example Action and test it? The other link you reference is not a good example. `why he added the mnemonic?` - a user should be able to use a mouse or the keyboard to perform an Action. The mnemonic allows you to use the keyboard. Again, this is standard Swing functionality. You need to read the Swing tutorial to learn the basics of using Swing.

Comment: but why mnemonic? i mean, correct me if i'm wrong, but as far as i know to add function for the button, you only need actionlistener. if mnemonic is for keyboard, why is it needed? please enlighten me

Comment: @luh, `why is it needed?` - have you ever used a GUI before? Have you ever seen a button with an underlined letter? This allows the user to invoke the button by using the keyboard instead of the mouse!